# How to set a description for an API Gateway using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I want to do this in the serverless.yml file but can't find the way in the docs.

I'd like to avoid doing this after every deploy from the CLI with something like

```
aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id <id> --patch-operations op=replace,path=/description,value='description'
```

Comment: Is your description value auto generated?

Comment: Nope, it is a text that I want to set manually

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [serverless-aws-documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-aws-documentation) plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using REST API (API Gateway v1), you can simply write the following in your **serverless.yml** file.

```
provider:
  apiGateway:
    description: Your custom description
```

But I don't have a solution if you are using HTTP API (API Gateway v2)